# C++: Store data in Linked list in another linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I would like to ask how to store the linked list of Opt in linked list of CustomerData? The approach that I use right now is creating the two linked list separately. When I need print out all the receipt the I have key in, I need to use the if statement  (optical_data.currentOpticalTrace == customer_data.currentCustomerTrace) just can print out the receipt. However, each customer actually did not keep the optical_data in customer_data. Moreover, the optical node needs to run from the first node to the last node every time the customer loop. How to make the code more efficient and reduce the repeatable?

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;


    struct Frame
    {
        int index;
        string itemCode;
        string name;
        int quantity;
        double price;

    };

    struct CustomerData
    {
        string customerName;
        int currentCustomerTrace;

    };


    struct CustomerDataNode
    {
        CustomerData customer_data;
        CustomerDataNode *next;
        CustomerDataNode *c_head, *c_tail;


    };

    struct Opt
    {
        string SitemCode;
        string Sname;
        double Sprice;
        int Squantity;
        int currentOpticalTrace;
    };

    struct OptNode
    {
        Opt optical_data;
        OptNode *next;
        OptNode *o_head, *o_tail;
    };

    class PurchaseSell
    {
        private:        
            int customerTrace;
            int opticalTrace;
            Frame frame;    
            CustomerDataNode cNode;
            OptNode oNode;
            CustomerData customer;
            Opt opt;

        public:
            PurchaseSell();
            void mainMenu_Sell();
            void addOrder();
            void customerCreateNode();
            void opticalCreateNode();
            void printReceipt();
            void printAllReceipt();
            Opt getOrder(Opt,string, string, double, int);
            void viewFrame();
    };



    PurchaseSell::PurchaseSell()
    {
        customerTrace = 0;
        opticalTrace = 0;
        cNode.c_head = NULL;
        cNode.c_tail = NULL;
        oNode.o_head = NULL;
        oNode.o_tail = NULL;

        frame.index=1;
        frame.itemCode="F0001";
        frame.name="FRAME 1";
        frame.price=50.00;
        frame.quantity=20;


    }

    void PurchaseSell::mainMenu_Sell()
    {

        int optS;
        bool inputSell=true;

        system("cls");
        cout<<"\t\t\t************   WELCOME TO CLEAR VISION OPTICAL SHOP    ************"<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t Sell Menu"<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t 1. Make New Order"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t 2. Print All Receipt"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t\t\t************   *************************************   ************"<<endl<<endl;

        cout<<"Please enter your option"<<endl;
        cin>>optS;

        switch(optS)
        {
            case 1: 
                addOrder();
                break;

            case 2:
                printAllReceipt();
                break;

            default:
                cout<<"Invalid input.";
        }
    }


    void PurchaseSell::customerCreateNode()
    {
        CustomerDataNode *ctemp = new CustomerDataNode;
        ctemp->customer_data = customer;
        ctemp->next = NULL;
        if(cNode.c_head==NULL)
        {
            cNode.c_head=ctemp;
            cNode.c_tail=ctemp;
            ctemp=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            cNode.c_tail->next=ctemp;
            cNode.c_tail=ctemp;
        }
    }

    void PurchaseSell::opticalCreateNode()
    {
        OptNode *otemp = new OptNode;

        otemp->optical_data = opt;
        otemp->next = NULL;
        if(oNode.o_head==NULL)
        {
            oNode.o_head=otemp;
            oNode.o_tail=otemp;
            otemp=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            oNode.o_tail->next=otemp;
            oNode.o_tail=otemp;
        }
    }

    Opt PurchaseSell::getOrder(Opt o, string itemCode, string name, double price, int Squantity)
    {
        o.SitemCode = itemCode ;
        o.Sname = name ;
        o.Sprice = price ;
        o.Squantity = Squantity ;

        return o;
    }

    void PurchaseSell::viewFrame()
    {
        cout<<"\t\t\t************       GLASS FRAME LIST    ************"<<endl<<endl;
        cout << "Index" << setw(20) << "Item Code" << setw( 20 )  << "Name" << setw( 20 ) << "Quantity" << setw( 20 ) << "Price(RM)" << setw( 20 ) << endl;


        cout << setw( 5 )<< 1 << setw( 20 ) << frame.itemCode << setw( 20 ) << frame.name<< setw( 20 ) << frame.quantity << setw( 20 ) << frame.price << setw( 20 ) <<endl<<endl;
    }

    void PurchaseSell::addOrder()
    {
            int choice;
            int quantityS;
            int quantityOptical;
            int pairs = 0;                  

            system("cls");
            cout<<"Please enter the customer name:  "<<endl;
            cin>> customer.customerName;
            opticalTrace = opticalTrace +1;

            viewFrame();

            do{
                cout<<"Please enter quantity to buy:\n" <<endl;
                cin>>quantityS;

                quantityOptical = frame.quantity-quantityS;
                frame.quantity=quantityOptical ;

                opt=getOrder(opt, frame.itemCode, frame.name, frame.price*quantityS, quantityS);
                opt.currentOpticalTrace=opticalTrace;
                opticalCreateNode();                        

                cout<<"\n\nPlease enter your option\n"; 
                cout<<"1) Continue to add on other optical type\n";
                cout<<"2) Complete order\n" ;
                cin>>choice;


                if(choice==1)
                {
                    pairs = pairs+1;

                    if(pairs==4)
                    {
                        cout<<"Customer has reach the order maximum 4 pairs of optical orders regardless the optical type."<<endl<<endl;
                        customerTrace= customerTrace+1;
                        customer.currentCustomerTrace=customerTrace;
                        customerCreateNode();
                        printReceipt();

                    }
                }
                else
                {   customerTrace= customerTrace+1;
                    customer.currentCustomerTrace=customerTrace;
                    customerCreateNode();
                    printReceipt();

                }


            }while(choice==1 && !(pairs >=4) );


    }

    void PurchaseSell::printReceipt()
    {
            system("cls");
            CustomerDataNode *ctemp = new CustomerDataNode;
            OptNode *otemp = new OptNode;
            ctemp = cNode.c_head;
            otemp = oNode.o_head;
            while(ctemp!=NULL)
            {
                if(ctemp->customer_data.currentCustomerTrace==customerTrace)
                {   
                    cout<<"CurrentCustomerTrace:" <<  ctemp->customer_data.currentCustomerTrace<<endl;
                    cout<<"Customer Name:" << ctemp->customer_data.customerName<<endl;

                    cout << "Item Code" << setw( 20 )  << "Name" << setw( 20 ) << "Quantity" << setw( 20 ) << "Amount(RM)" << endl;
                    while(otemp!=NULL)
                    {
                        if(otemp->optical_data.currentOpticalTrace == opticalTrace)
                        {
                            cout << otemp->optical_data.SitemCode << setw( 20 ) 
                            <<otemp->optical_data.Sname << setw( 20 ) << otemp->optical_data.Squantity << setw( 20 ) << otemp->optical_data.Sprice <<endl<<endl;
                        }
                        otemp = otemp->next;    
                    }   
                }
                ctemp = ctemp->next;
            }
            system("PAUSE");

    }

    void PurchaseSell::printAllReceipt()
    {
            CustomerDataNode *ctemp = new CustomerDataNode;
            OptNode *otemp = new OptNode;
            ctemp = cNode.c_head;
            otemp = oNode.o_head;
            while(ctemp!=NULL)
            {   
                    cout<<"CurrentCustomerTrace:" <<  ctemp->customer_data.currentCustomerTrace<<endl;
                    cout<<"Customer Name:" << ctemp->customer_data.customerName<<endl;

                    cout << "Item Code" << setw( 20 )  << "Name" << setw( 20 ) << "Quantity" << setw( 20 ) << "Amount(RM)" << endl;
                            otemp = oNode.o_head;

                    while(otemp!=NULL)
                    {
                        if(otemp->optical_data.currentOpticalTrace == ctemp->customer_data.currentCustomerTrace)
                        {
                            cout << otemp->optical_data.SitemCode << setw( 20 ) <<otemp->optical_data.Sname 
                                << setw( 20 ) << otemp->optical_data.Squantity << setw( 20 ) << otemp->optical_data.Sprice <<endl<<endl;
                        }
                        otemp = otemp->next;    
                    }   

                ctemp = ctemp->next;
            }
            system("PAUSE");
    }

    int main()
    {

        PurchaseSell p;
        while(true)
        {
            p.mainMenu_Sell();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are writing your own linked list and not using the existing ones from the standard library? Also that is way too much code, which exact section is giving you trouble? If this code is working and you want a review then take it to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: *The approach that I use right now is creating the two linked list separately.* -- If this is a school exercise, the approach should be to create a generic linked list class, i.e `template <typename T> class LinkedList {...};` and just use it instead of creating two separate sets of linked list code.  Like this: `LinkedList<optical_data> oDataList; LinkedList<customer_data> cDataList;`

Comment: @UnholySheep the code is work. Just that the design of code that I wrote is not efficient. Thank for your suggestion to go to CodeReview for review.